# Ring of global sections of a large twist of a vector bundle is not zero

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is [Vakil 18.5 D](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf) (the first claim), self-study. Please note this is an intermediate step in the classification of vector bundles on $\mathbb P^1_k$, so we may not use that result.

We have to show that if $\mathcal E$ is a rank $r$ locally free sheaf on $\mathbb P^1_k$, then for $m <<0$,

$$\operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal O(m), \mathcal E) \neq 0$$

To begin, we note that the sheaf Hom $\operatorname{\mathcal Hom}(\mathcal O(m), \mathcal E) \simeq \mathcal E(-m)$ by a previous exercise. Hence we need to show

$$\Gamma (\mathbb P^1_k, \mathcal E(-m)) \neq 0$$

for $m << 0$. Vakil then says to use Serre vanishing, which gives us that

$$H^i (\mathbb P^1_k, \mathcal E(-m)) = 0$$

for $m <<0$ and $i > 0$, but I do not see why this forces $H^0$ to be nonzero.

Comment: A good solution requires more context - it's easy to imagine this result being proven in several different ways, any of which could be proven in Vakil's text before or after it. What material have you covered recently?

Comment: This comes right after the introduction of Serre duality (which we are supposed to use on the second part of the problem that I didn't list), and it's in the middle of the chapter on Cohomology. I would say the most significant things recently learned are Serre Vanishing, the cohomology of $\mathbb P^n_A$, and Riemann-Roch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attempt at a solution:

We wish to show $\Gamma (\mathbb P^1_k, \mathcal E(-m)) \neq 0$ for $m <<0$.

Filter $\mathcal E$ as

$$0 = \mathcal E_0 \subset \mathcal E_1 \subset ... \subset \mathcal E_r = \mathcal E$$

such that each subquotient is some invertible sheaf $\mathcal L_i \simeq \mathcal O(n_i)$ on $\mathbb P^1_k$ using [Stacks OAYP](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AYP) (which does not use the classification of vector bundles on $\mathbb P^1_k$, and I have been through its proof before for previous exercises.)

This admits an exact sequence

$$0 \to \mathcal E_{r - 1} \to \mathcal E \to \mathcal O(n_r) \to 0$$

By Serre Vanishing, if $m<<0$, $H^i(\mathbb P^1_k, \mathcal E(-m)) = 0$ for all $i > 0$.

Tensor the above exact sequence by $\mathcal O(-m)$ for $m << 0$ that the above holds; another condition will be added to the size of $m$ momentarily. This preserves exactness, and gives

$$0 \to \mathcal E_{r - 1}(-m) \to \mathcal E(-m) \to \mathcal O(n_r - m) \to 0$$

By the Serre vanishing observation above, taking global sections is an exact functor, giving

$$0 \to \Gamma (\mathbb P^1_k, \mathcal E_{r - 1}(-m)) \to \Gamma(\mathbb P^1_k,\mathcal E(-m)) \to \Gamma(\mathbb P^1_k,\mathcal O(n_r - m) ) \to 0$$

But we already know by Cohomology of $\mathbb P^n_A$ that $\Gamma(\mathbb P^1_k,\mathcal O(n_r - m) ) \neq 0$ for $m << 0$, so impose that additional condition on the size of $m$ before you twist above, and you will have

$$\Gamma(\mathbb P^1_k,\mathcal E(-m)) \neq 0$$